# find xargs rm with filename pattern in variable

Tags: bash, find, rm

Command like this:

```
find /directory -type f -name "*.txt" -print | xargs rm
```

delete every `.txt` file in directory and subdirectories, and that's ok. But, if we make a variable or array for file extension and then put `find`, e.g.,

```
TXT=(*.txt)
for ii in ${TXT[@]}; do
  find /directory -type f -name $TXT -print | xargs rm
done
```

this commands do not delete `.txt` files in subdirectories. Why? How to change this second code to delete files in subdirectories?

PS: I used an array, because I have more than one file extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array assignment,

```
TXT=(*.txt)
```

will expand the `*.txt` pattern to the list filenames in the current directory that matches that pattern. The shell would do this at the time of the assignment.  This is not what you want.  You want to give `find` the literal string `*.txt`, like so:

```
pattern='*.txt'
find /directory -type f -name "$pattern" -exec rm {} +
```

Here, I've also gotten rid of `xargs rm` and I'm instead executing `rm` directly from `find`.  Most current implementations of `find` could use the non-standard `-delete` in place of `-exec rm {} +`:

```
pattern='*.txt'
find /directory -type f -name "$pattern" -delete
```

Note that there is no need for a loop here as we're only dealing with a single pattern. Also note that the quoting of `"$pattern"` in the call to `find` is important, otherwise the pattern would be replaced by all matching filenames in the current directory before `find` starts.

For several patterns, you could do a loop like so:

```
patterns=( '*.txt' '*.tmp' )
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
    find /directory -type f -name "$pattern" -delete
done
```

The quoting in the array assignment is essential as it stops the shell from using the patterns as filename globbing patterns there and then.  The quoting of `"${patterns[@]}"` and `"$pattern"` is likewise important, for the same reason.

Another approach is to make only a single call to `find`, even if you have multiple patterns.  This would speed things up a fair bit if `/directory` is a large directory hierarchy.  The following code does that by building up an array of `-name` tests for `find` to use:

```
patterns=( '*.txt' '*.tmp' )

name_tests=( )
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
    name_tests+=( -o -name "$pattern" )
done

# "${name_tests[@]:1}" removes the initial "-o", which shouldn't be there.
name_tests=( '(' "${name_tests[@]:1}" ')' )

find /directory -type f "${name_tests[@]}" -delete
```

In the above script, the actual command executed at the end will be

```
find /directory -type f '(' -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.tmp' ')' -delete
```

... which will delete all regular files that have filename suffixes `.txt` *or* `.tmp` anywhere in or below the directory `/directory`.